# How can I make xml file in android according to design in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

and cannot solve problem problem with xml editing:

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/half_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/main_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/main_padding"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_padding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/news_category_color"
            android:id="@+id/newsCategory"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/news_date_color"
            android:id="@+id/newsDate"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/news_category_color"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/reklama"
            android:text="@string/reklama"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_offline"
            android:id="@+id/offlineIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_stroke"
            android:padding="3dp"
            >

            <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/placeholder_small"
                />

            <uz.muloqot.daryo.view.DaryoTextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/place_holder_bg"
                android:textColor="@color/place_holder_text"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                />

            <uz.muloqot.daryo.view.DaryoWebImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

        <uz.muloqot.daryo.view.PTSansTextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_padding"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/post_title_color"
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

while producing this code I get smth. like this:
[image]

however I should get this:

[image]

Comment: you can use either CARDVIEW or RECYCLERVIEW for getting desired output

Answer (score 1):

Add your code inside [CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) And Add RecyclerView

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:elevation="5dp">

    Add Your Code HERE

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, however, i  dont need recycler view , it is in list view , I just want to make the block of image that was mentioned to look like in the pic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use recyclerview layout ,Check the pic [here](https://traversoft.com/blog/images/favebakes-intro.png)

Comment: thanks , and how can I move text? so it is right of the little image